# SSRS (Report Builder) Min Value and Max Value from Same Dataset

Tags: max, ssrs-2012, min, reportbuilder3.0

I am attempting to extract data from a database that has an error in it. I can't resolve the error (it's a "design feature"), so i have to try to query around it. Here's how it is stored.

```
Record ID | Create Date | Update Date | Record Status
123       | 05/01/2018  | 05/01/2018  | Active
123       | 05/08/2018  | 05/08/2018  | Active
123       | 05/15/2018  | 05/15/2018  | Closed
123       | 05/22/2018  | 05/22/2018  | Closed
456       | 06/02/2018  | 06/02/2018  | Pending
456       | 06/09/2018  | 06/09/2018  | Active
456       | 06/16/2018  | 06/16/2018  | Active
456       | 06/23/2018  | 06/23/2018  | Suspended
```

And so on. As you can see, the Create Date and Update Date values match on each row. The Create Date value is supposed to be the date the Record ID was initially created, but it's actually being captured as the date the Record ID update was created.

What I need is a report that brings me a single row per Record ID that shows me the minimum Create Date and the maximum Update Date, so that the result looks something like this:

```
Record ID | Create Date | Update Date | Record Status
123       | 05/01/2018  | 05/22/2018  | Closed
456       | 06/02/2018  | 06/23/2018  | Suspended
```

I've tried using the MIN and MAX aggregate functions in the Query Designer, and that works just fine until I add any other field that may change through the life of the record. I get this:

```
Record ID | Create Date | Update Date | Record Status
123       | 05/01/2018  | 05/08/2018  | Active
123       | 05/15/2018  | 05/22/2018  | Closed
456       | 06/02/2018  | 06/02/2018  | Pending
456       | 06/09/2018  | 06/16/2018  | Active
456       | 06/23/2018  | 06/23/2018  | Suspended
```

I'm relatively new to Report Builder, though I think I'm picking up its concepts quickly. What am I missing here?

Edited to add that when I use the Query Designer, the query text looks like this:

```
SELECT
  DB.RECORD.RECORD_ID
  ,DB.RECORD.RECORD_STATUS_CODE
  ,MAX(DB.RECORD.RECORD_CREATED_DATE) AS Max_RECORD_CREATED_DATE
  ,MIN(DB.RECORD.RECORD_UPDATED_DATE) AS Min_RECORD_UPDATED_DATE
FROM
  DB.RECORD
GROUP BY
  DB.RECORD.RECORD_ID
  ,DB.RECORD.RECORD_STATUS_CODE
```

Comment: Would you mind including the query used?  It seems like this could be fixed with a `GROUP BY RecordID` but it's tough to tell without the query.

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant ways to do this using CTEs but this is a simple solution.

First I replicated your data sample and stuffed in into a table variable `@t`. Then all we do is group by recordid, getting the min create date and max update date (ignoring the status for now). We join to this subquery back to your original table, joining on recordid and update date, this will give us the last record for the record id and get the status from there.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ([Record ID] int, [Create Date] date, [Update Date] date, [Record Status] varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(123, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', 'Active'),
(123, '2018-05-08', '2018-05-08', 'Active'),
(123, '2018-05-15', '2018-05-15', 'Closed'),
(123, '2018-05-22', '2018-05-22', 'Closed'),
(456, '2018-06-02', '2018-06-02', 'Pending'),
(456, '2018-06-09', '2018-06-09', 'Active'),
(456, '2018-06-16', '2018-06-16', 'Active'),
(456, '2018-06-23', '2018-06-23', 'Suspended')


SELECT 
     g.[Record ID], g.[Create Date], g.[Update Date], t.[Record Status]
 FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT [Record ID], MIN([Create Date]) AS [Create Date], MAX([Update Date]) AS [Update Date] 
            FROM @t
            GROUP BY [Record ID]
    ) g
    JOIN @t t ON g.[Record ID] = t.[Record ID] and g.[Update Date] = t.[Update Date]
 ORDER BY [Record ID]
```

Here's link to a SQL Fiddle that shows the results. The only difference with this version is the table name.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0bb22/1/0

**UPDATE** Based on your dataset query

This may not be 100% as I don;t have all your data to test but you probably just need the following.

```
 SELECT 
     g.RECORD_ID, g.RECORD_CREATED_DATE, g.lastUpdateDate, t.RECORD_STATUS_CODE
 FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT RECORD_ID, MIN(RECORD_CREATED_DATE) AS RECORD_CREATED_DATE, MAX(RECORD_UPDATED_DATE) AS lastUpdateDate 
            FROM DB.RECORD
            GROUP BY RECORD_ID
    ) g
    JOIN DB.RECORD t ON g.RECORD_ID = t.RECORD_ID and g.lastUpdateDate = t.RECORD_UPDATED_DATE
 ORDER BY RECORD_ID
```

Comment: The results in the SQL Fiddle look exactly like what I would need. And I think I see where you're going with the @t join concept. What I'm not sure about is that block right under the "INSERT INTO @t VALUES" line. I have over 400,000 Record IDs in this database. How do I get all of those into the VALUES table here? Does the "DECLARE @t" line generate it for me?

Comment: All the code up to the just before the `SELECT` is just to create the sample data table. 
The @t table is just a temporary table that I could use to put the data in to test with, you don't need any of that, you can just swap out @t for your real table in the SELECT statement.

If you look at the fiddle, you'll see the left side creates the sample data when you build the schema and the right side is the actual code to get your results from the sample data.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include your table and column names so it's (hopefully) easier to understand.

Comment: I attempted your suggested code. I copied it exactly, replacing the example field names here with the actual field names. It didn't work. I'm guessing it's a typo on my part somewhere because the error message is "Incorrect syntax near '.'." But I can't figure out where the mistake is...

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the CREATE script for the DB.RECORD table. Right-click it in SSMS and choose, "Script Table as => CREATE to => New Query Window" You can strip out all the constraints and references if you like and post the script in your question.

Comment: Sorry, Alan, I must be missing something. I'm not familiar with SSMS. I use Report Builder 3.0 (2012) and the Report Manager site associated with it. When viewing data on the Report Manager, I don't have an option to "Script Table as." I've tried your query several times, but each time I get a syntax error that appears to be related to a "." or "AS" instance in the text.

Comment: SSMS is SQL Server Management Studio. You can download it for free. You'll find it much easier to build and test the queries there before copying them to the dataset query. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017